# Sorting with constraint no consecutive equals

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I would like to sort a news feed according to created date, which is trivial, but I don't want 2 consecutive posts with the same userId field.

This might not be theoritically possible because what if I have only 2 posts with the same userId field?

I am looking for an algorithm that sorts according to fieldA but doesn't have 2 consecutive elements with the same fieldB.

It would also nice to have a parametrized algorithm about the required number of different posts between same user's different posts. (In the first scenario this parameter is 1)

I'm not looking for performance (O(n^2) would be okay) but a clever & simple way, maybe with 5 lines of code.

Language doesn't matter but Javascript is preferred.

Comment: 1) sort 2) filter / intersperse according to your rules

Comment: So if sorting by date gives you ABAAB, do you want that to be rearranged to ABABA? Or do you want to delete that third `A` post, giving ABAB?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem in 5 lines is somewhat difficult,I'm trying to give a short pseudocode and you may translate it to js.

First we group the input to A[1],A[2],...,A[k].A[i] is a container contains all posts of i-th user,this can be easily done via **O(n)** scanning.

code:

```
for i = 1 to k
    lastOccurPosition[i] = -intervalLength; //that is the interval length specified by parameter 
for i = 1 to k
    sort(A[i]);
for i = 1 to n
    minElement = INF; //find the minimum
    minUserId = -1;  //record whose post is minimun
    for j = 1 to k
        if(i - lastOccurPosition[i] <= intervalLength) //if the user has occured within interval length,the user's post shouldn't be choosen
            continue;
        if(A[j][1] < minElement)
            minElement = A[j][1];
            minUserId = j;
    answer[i] = minElement; //put min element into answer array
    lastOccurPosition[minUserId] = i; //update choosen user's last occur position
    A[minUserId].pop_front(); //delele first element
```

It is easy to analyse this algorithm's complexity is **O(n^2)** and I haven't thought out a more concise solution.

Hope to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Put the atributes in an array, and sort that array:

```
arr.sort();
```

Put the second atribute in another array and sort that array according to the first one.

```
var newarr = [arr[0]];
for (var i=1; i<arr.length; i++) {
   if (arr[i]!=arr[i-1]) newarr.push(arr[i]);
}
```

Now this just remove duplicates.

This all feels kind of trivial, am I missing something?
Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Gijs